# Setting State in Asynchronous funtion always returns false

Tags: react-native, authentication

I am trying to  make `User Authentication` and  decode  `User credentials`  from `JWT Token`  and also keep track of whether  user is logged in. so signIn method is an asynchronous function so when I update isLogged it always return false. This is the code below.

```js
const useAuth = () => {
  const tokenKey = 'authToken';
  const [isLogged, setIslogged] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [loggedUser, setloggedUser] = useState<authUsers | null>(null);
  const {user, setUser} = useContext(AuthContext);

  const singIn = async function LoginUser(token: string) {
    console.log('calling singin');
    if (isLogged && loggedUser) return;

    console.log('The USer was not logged in');

    try {
      console.log('calling singin try');
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(tokenKey, token);
      console.log('calling singin try setItem with token:', token);
      const tok = await AsyncStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
      console.log('calling singin try getItem with token:', tok);

      if (!token) return;
      console.log('Token Found Trying to decode');
      const decodedUser = convertTokenToUser(token);
      if (!decodedUser) return;
      console.log('Decode Successfull Here ', decodedUser);
      setIslogged(true);
      if (decodedUser) {
        console.log('Setting is logged to true ');
        console.log('User logged in', isLogged);
        console.log('Setting logged user done');
        setloggedUser(decodedUser);
        console.log('User logged in', decodedUser);
        setUser(decodedUser);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setIslogged(false);
    }
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const getTokenAndSignIn = async () => {
      const token = await getToken();
      if (token) {
        singIn(token);
      }
    };
    getTokenAndSignIn();
  }, []);

  return {isLogged, singIn, singOut, getToken, loggedUser};
};

export default useAuth;
```

this is the output on my console...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPiRy.png)

I want isLogged to return true so that I can render the user Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

The `useState` hook won't update its state *until the next render* (async). Think of `setIsLogged` (and all state updates) as "low priority instruction", which can be detected and acted upon *later* by "slow processes" e.g. rendering

The rest of your logic, is correct in that it doesn't use `isLogged` directly - and is thus allowed to execute quickly.

You can, for your sanity, or if you need a side-effect use the `useEffect` hook to log when the change to `isLogged` is detected

```
   useEffect(() => {
        console.log('User logged in', isLogged);
        // Some other side effect

   }, [isLogged])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you get false in line `console.log('User logged in', isLogged);` it's because setState is async, so state changes won't be visible immediately in the same call of the function. Your state should be updated in component where you use that hook (of course if other conditions are met)